# Can we deploy wit.ai on a Private network or server ?

Tags: deployment, wit.ai

I am using Wit.ai public cloud in my application but i wanted to check if there is any way we can deploy this in a private cloud or locally.

As I am using this for some secure data interactions too. Security is a major concern.

Any answers and ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Wit service cannot be deployed to a private cloud or locally.

Maybe you could try an open source NLP solution like MyCroft. https://mycroft.ai

Comment: Is it possible to locally deploy or host Mycroft ?